# Physicalist Critiques of Error Theory

Tags: metaethics, moral-realism

Mackie’s Error Theory makes two parallel arguments that moral qualities have no place in a naturalistic understanding of our universe. That (1) such a bizarre epistemic power unlike any other we possess must exist to detect moral properties, and (2) moral properties are unlike any other physical properties studied by the sciences. Thus, all moral judgments are in error or false, since they concern unphysical properties of phenomena.

I’m well aware of how non-physicalists or non-naturalists would react to Mackie’s arguments. What I’m curious about are responses from those that are *physicalists* (or naturalists) and retain *moral realism*. What are their counter-arguments?

Comment: I've not read the work of any naturalist moral realists, but I'll note that we have other faculties that share characteristics with our sense of morality: our sense of beauty, sense of other minds, sense of teleological ends, sense of the distinction between reality and dreams, sense that things persist when they are not observed, sense of wholeness of objects, sense of causality, sense of the fixedness of the past. All of these senses involve our mind adding to what is delivered by our physical senses.

Comment: @DavidGudeman - is that, however, consonant with physicalism? Are physicalists, for example, realists about beauty? or teleology?"

Comment: No, but physicalists can't be realists about morality either. I thought the comment was long enough without making that additional point.

Comment: @DavidGudeman One might perhaps add logic to the list. There are naturalistic accounts of logic, but it is more mainstream to think of logic is *a priori* knowable. In that case, logical knowledge seems to be just as bizarre as moral knowledge.

Comment: @Bumble, good point. And, in fact, all mathematical knowledge.